# Unlike after like causes scroll to bottom (page tab app)

Tags: facebook

I have a Facebook page tab app, that is published every year for a month. It's a beauty contest, every like on a girl's card is a vote. It worked perfectly the last 2 years, and during the current test period as well. But since I've published the app this year and the likes started to come, the page started to scroll to the bottom of the page on each like removal. (Update: only on unlikes after a previous like.) My current workaround is the code below. It is ugly, because the page now jumps up and down. How could I prevent the unwanted scroll to the bottom, when I unlike someone?

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function(url,elem){
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
    FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,300);
});
```

Here is the live app: https://www.facebook.com/worldismineofficial/app/232173270308197/?app_data=skipintro

Comment: If I simply load the app and start to unlike my previous likes, then it's fine. Only unlikes after a like cause this issue. So if I like someone and unlike her right after, the page scrolls to the bottom. (And to the top then, thanks to my ugly script.)

Comment: I've added a scroll Event Listener Breakpoint in Chrome DevTools, so now I'm sure that the scroll is called by a Facebook JS function named "ca", not by my own code. But I still don't know how could I prevent this.

Comment: File a bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/246765672326394/